# Tounament has champion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let  $G(V,E)$ be a simple directed graph such that

• for each pair of vertices $u\neq v$, exactly one of the two edges $(u,v)$ or $(v,u)$ is in $E$

Prove that there is a vertex $s \in V$ such that for all vertex $v\neq s$,

• either $(s,v) \in E$,

• or there exists  $u \in V$ such that  $(s,u) \in E $and$ (u,v) \in E.$

I don't know how to prove it please give me some help to prove it.

Comment: This is the version we have seen before.   I  couldn't find the duplicate quickly, but it is there.

Comment: Please let me know the duplicate if you find that.

Comment: Here's one duplicate but probably there are others...

Comment: @Misha Lavrov thank you for your searching duplicate.